# JSON/PHP - Empty Array

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to display JSON in my PHP file. The problem is that it doesn't show anything, like it was empty.

**Code**

```
<?php
include ('conexion.php');
//$id = $_GET['id'];
$sql = "SELECT tbl_usuarios.idUsuario, tbl_usuarios.nombrec, tbl_actividades.idUsuario, tbl_actividades.fec_actividad, tbl_actividades.nombre FROM tbl_actividades INNER JOIN tbl_usuarios ON tbl_usuarios.idUsuario = tbl_actividades.idUsuario WHERE tbl_usuarios.idUsuario = 1";

if($conexion){

    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)) die();

        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $arreglo[] = $data;
        }
        echo json_encode($arreglo);
    }else{
        die ("error");
    }

?>
```

It only shows when I use `print_r($arreglo)`.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($arreglo)`?

Comment: What does the browsers "View page source" feature show?

Comment: On which line in that code did you try `print_r($arreglo)`? It seems possible that the query failed and the script died before it could do anything with `$arreglo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your database objects are in Spanish, it is most probable that your result array, `$arreglo` is not encoded in utf-8. Because to Spanish uses special characters like 'ñ', it is most probable your default database encoding is not utf-8. When such characters are encountered, the function `json_encode` fails and shows nothing.  Because such function only works with utf-8 results.

One way to deal with this is to pass your array through this function so it cast everything into utf-8. add the following function to your PHP.

```
 function cast_data_types ($value) {
      if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = array_map('cast_data_types',$value);
        return $value;
      }
      if (is_numeric($value)) {
        if(strpos('.', $value)===false) return (float)$value;
        return (int) $value;
      }
      return utf8_encode((string)$value);
    }
```

You can also apply `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` to properly show special characters back.

so instead of `echo json_encode($arreglo);`

you should input  `echo json_encode(cast_data_types($arreglo),JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

If the above does not work you can always use `json_last_error()` 
to check what error was encountered during json_encode or json_decode operations.

> http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: Nice answer. It's a bit speculative, but the assumption is reasonable. Might want to mention that it's possible to check for errors encountered by `json_encode` to verify that that's truly what the problem is here.

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for the edit, sorry for my english it is not my first language. I am going to edit in what you say about checking for errors.

Comment: Your English seems fine to me! I really only edited because of the typo in "function". Normally I wouldn't have bothered to edit just to capitalize a couple of things.